# Get size of worksheet area in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, pixel, area, worksheet

I need to get the width and height in pixels of the worksheet area in Excel VBA. This is the area where cells in a worksheet are displayed. Thus it must exclude all other Excel UI elements. I have attempted to use GetSystemMetrics and SystemParametersInfo but found no solution.

Comment: Examine the properties and methods of the Window object

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the following code can be of help:

```
MsgBox ("Width in points = " & ActiveWindow.Width & Chr(13) & _ 
"Depth in points = " & ActiveWindow.Height & Chr(13) & _ 
"Width in Pixels = " & ActiveWindow.PointsToScreenPixelsX(ActiveWindow.Width) & Chr(13) & _ 
"Depth in Pixels = " & ActiveWindow.PointsToScreenPixelsY(ActiveWindow.Height))
```

<sub>Code originally found here: http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=36696 (by Ger Plante)</sub>

Comment: This gives the wrong values for me. It prints:

    Width in points: 1036,5
    Depth in points: 565,5
    Width in pixels: -285
    Depth in pixels: 524

It should be printing

    Width in points: 221,29
    Depth in points: 489
    Width in pixels: 1554
    Depth in pixels: 652